# How can I make an adaptive list to check against another adaptive list?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I apologize from the start as I am not allowed to share the workbook I am working on (it has confidential information from work) but I will do my best to explain what is happening and what my issue is.

I have two sheets, "Tracker" and "Reviewers". In the tracker names are recorded in column L and their submission is recorded in column M. Everything runs on a serial code in column A so there are blank cells between names. Some people have multiple submissions so their names show multiple times in column L. In the reviewers sheet, I have:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(Tracker!L4:L4999,Tracker!L4:L4999<>0))
```

In cell A2 to pull all the names of people who have a submission. This works flawlessly and adapts to include any new people. Then in cell B2 I have written:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(ISBLANK(FILTER(Tracker!$L$4:$M$4999,Tracker!$L$4:$L$4999=Reviewers!A2#))=TRUE,1,0))
```

The idea here was to get a count of how many "submissions" people have without actually writing anything. It is filtering the list of names and submissions by name in the list we just created, checking if their "submission" is a blank cell, then adding them up. Issue is that it works when I filter by cell A2 but not when I filter by the function that spills out of cell A2 (A2#). I need it to be adaptive so if new names are added it can make the list longer, hence why I cannot just pull the cells down the list (A2, A3, A4,...). How would you go about getting a check of how many are blank like this?

As an example, Tracker could have:

| Name | Submission |
| --- | --- |
| Jim | Idea |
| Bob | Idea |
| Pam |  |
| Sam | Idea |
| Jim |  |
| Bob | Idea |
| Jim |  |
| Pam | Idea |

And Reviewers should return:

| Name | #Blank |
| --- | --- |
| Jim | 2 |
| Bob | 0 |
| Pam | 1 |
| Sam | 0 |

I hope this makes sense and I hope you can help me edit the equation in cell B2 of the Reviewers sheet to be adaptive and spill the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=LET(d,DROP(FILTER(A:B,A:A<>""),1),
     n,INDEX(d,,1),
     s,INDEX(d,,2),
     u,UNIQUE(n),
     m,MMULT(--(TOROW(n)=u),--(s="")),
HSTACK(u,m))
```

Change the filter range (and maybe the lines to drop) and the index numbers to your situation.

[image]

I think this would work in your case:

```
=LET(d,DROP(FILTER(Tracker!$L$4:$M$4999,Tracker!$M$4:$M$4999<>""),1),
     n,INDEX(d,,1),
     s,INDEX(d,,2),
     u,UNIQUE(n),
     m,MMULT(--(TOROW(n)=u),--(s="")),
HSTACK(u,m))
```

Comment: Hi. I think I can kind of make sense of this but I cannot make it work. it spits out #VALUE! Do you put this in D2 and it spills over into E?

Comment: I got it to work! It needed to be
=LET(d,DROP(FILTER(Tracker!$L$4:$M$4999,Tracker!$L$4:$L$4999<>""),1),
     n,INDEX(d,,1),
     s,INDEX(d,,2),
     u,UNIQUE(n),
     m,MMULT(--(TOROW(n)=u),--(s="")),
HSTACK(u,m))
and I had to split the HSTACK because I needed to reference the two columns individually

Comment: Would you be able to explain what is happening behind the scenes for m? that's the only part I do not understand.

Comment: Come to think of it, in your case you shouldn't use drop, since you filter from the first row of data (without header).

Comment: What exacly is drop doing? And are you saying I can just remove drop and it'll work the same?

Comment: `Drop(range,1)` will remove the first row of the range  `drop(range,,1)` the first column. You can also drop more rows by putting a higher number for argument, or a negative argument to drop a number of rows from the last row of the range(/or array)

Comment: Okay I understand now! Thanks!. Do you mind explaining the m,MMULT(--(TOROW(n)=u),--(s="")) bit?

Comment: I will do that later. That's less simple to explain

Comment: I think this may help you understand the use of MMULT to use for conditional counts or conditional sums: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AhxknrNHLDPC8zx8bg_38I0IOLEf?e=S85WbJ

Answer (score 3):

**Power Pivot & Measure**:

Just for the sakes of alternatives I added a Power Pivot Table option:

[image]

Steps I took:

- Select `A1:B9`;
- In the 'Power Pivot' tab add the data to the Data Model;
- Created a new measure named '#Blank', refering to:

  ```
  =COUNTBLANK([Submission])
  ```
- Add a Power Pivot Table;
- Under the 'PivotTable Fields' add name to the 'Rows' area and the newly created measure to 'Values';
- Under the 'PivotTable Options' choose to show items when no data on rows;
- Under the 'PivotTable Options' choose to show a zero for empty cells.

Did I overcomplicate this? Possibly!

---

**PowerQuery**:

Another cool idea is to load the data into PowerQuery. Now you could transform the 'submission' column, and group this by 'name'.

[image]

Here is the M-Code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Group = Table.Group(Source, {"Name"}, {{"#Blank", each List.Sum(List.Transform([Submission], (n)=> if n is null then 1 else 0)), type number}})
in
    Group
```

Or:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Group = Table.Group(Source, {"Name"}, {{"#Blank", each List.Accumulate([Submission],0,(s,c)=>if c is null then s+1 else s), type number}})
in
    Group
```

Or, even better:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Group = Table.Group(Source, {"Name"}, {{"#Blank", each List.Count(List.Select([Submission],(n)=> n is null)), type number}})
in
    Group
```

Comment: Ill be honest. Almost all of this went over my head. Its super impressive but I have no idea how you're doing it

Comment: @LightOfTheNight no worries. I have to admit the above actually *is* complicated. Glad you found the answer that suits your needs and knowledge!

Comment: I changed the table in the question to change "Blank" to actual blanks (as I noticed this was used as logic in his initial formula). That results in your code being correct, but reflecting the old data.

Comment: Thanks @P.b, trying to edit my answer accordingly!